# Subsetting an array, then creating a list of averages from those groups in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment I'm struggling with. Just to preface: I am not allowed to make a 2d array, nor am I supposed to make a nested loop. I have not been able to find help that doesn't involve one or the other of those, even in our textbook. 
I have to make a method that takes a list of 175 scores, finds the average of groups of 7 scores from the array, and then store the averages found in a new array. this is what I already have in the method:

lines is how many total scores there are recorded, `pointData` is the array storing the scores themselves.

```
double[] averages = new double[lines];

int total=0;
double average=0;
for (int index = 0; index < pointData.Length; index++)
{
    total += pointData[index];
    double average =  total/7
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can use the `%` operator to determine if seven scores have been added to the index.

```
int i = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < pointData.length; index++)
{
      //Add the data from pointData to the index
      averages[i] += pointData[index];
      //if seven scores have been added
      if(index % 7 == 6) {
         //divide by seven to get average
         averages[i] = averages[i]/7.0;
         i++;
      }
}
```

The general logic is add seven scores in a given index. Check to see if seven scores have been added. If so, divide the sum in the index by seven to get the average and then increment `i` to move to the next index in `averages`